# Can I leave the underlying member of my custom Scala TraversableView null?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a tree object that implements lazy depth-first-search as a `TraversableView`.

```
import collection.TraversableView

case class Node[T](label: T, ns: Node[T]*)

case class Tree[T](root: Node[T]) extends TraversableView[T, Traversable[_]] {
    protected def underlying = null

    def foreach[U](f: (T) => U) {
        def dfs(r: Node[T]): TraversableView[T, Traversable[_]] = {
            Traversable(r.label).view ++ r.ns.flatMap(dfs(_))
        }
        dfs(root).foreach(f)
    }
}
```

This is appealingly concise and appears to work; however, the `underlying = null` method makes me nervous because I don't understand what it means. (IntelliJ wrote that line for me.) I suppose it might be correct, because in this case there is no underlying strict representation of the tree, but I'm  not sure.

Is the above code correct, or do I have to do something more with `underlying`?

Comment: Even if that is correct, I would never recommend using `null` like that. Instead, try throwing a descriptive exception so that if `underlying` ever does end up getting called you'll know exactly when and where instead of getting a confusing null pointer exception after the `null` value was propagated elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users of views will expect to be able to call `force` to get a strict collection. With your implementation, calling `force` on a tree (or any transformation of a tree—e.g., `tree.take(10).filter(pred)`, etc.) will result in a null pointer exception.

This may be fine with you—you'll still be able to force evaluation using `toList`, for example (although you should follow the advice in DaoWen's comment if you go that route).

The actual contents of `underlying` should never get used, though, so there's an easy fix—just make it an appropriately typed empty collection:

```
protected def underlying = Vector.empty[T]
```

Now if a user calls `tree.force`, they'll get a vector of labels, statically typed as a `Traversable[T]`.